# How to pass variable to another content script in Google Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing Google Chrome extension. I want to separate my libraries which I wrote in different content scripts. I've created a simple loader for injecting scripts orderly.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(showIntercomAction);

function insert(tabId, files) {
    var file = files.shift();
    if (file) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, extend({file: file}, insertOptions), function () {
            insert(tabId, files);
        });
    }
}
function showIntercomAction(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
        var files = ['js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js', 'js/RangeSliderThumbPainter.js', 'js/content.js'];
        insert(tabId, files);
    }
```

in RangeSliderThumbPainter I wrote this

```
window.TEST = "TEST FROM RANGE";
```

And in Content.js try to use it

```
console.log("TEST in content.js is ", TEST); // undefined
```

I created variable in RangeSliderThumbPainter.js and I want to use it in content.js. How to implement this stuff?

Comment: What problem did you encounter when you tried to access the variable? Content scripts executed by the same extension run in the same JavaScript environment.

Comment: @RobW variable is undefined. I've added example.

Comment: Please try out your example before posting it. If the file was really not defined, then the second script would throw a ReferenceError instead of printing undefined.

Comment: @RobW RangeSliderThumbPainter was injected success. It seems like each injected file has own window.